# My DataService using BehaviorSubject is not workiing

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I am trying to implement a client-side data service in Angular 5.  I am very new to Angular and this represents my first attempt at implementing a data service.

Here is my DataService class:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
private url: string;
private binomialResultSource = new BehaviorSubject(new  Observable<IBinomialResult>());
public binomialResult = this.binomialResultSource.asObservable();

constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {
    this.url = "api/BinomialResult/GetBinomialResult/0/0";
    this.binomialResultSource.next(this.http.get<IBinomialResult>(this.url));
}

getBinomialResult(inputValues: any) {
    this.url = "api/BinomialResult/GetBinomialResult/" + inputValues.failureCount + "/" + inputValues.demandCount;
    this.binomialResultSource.next(this.http.get<IBinomialResult>(this.url));
} 
//private url: string;
//public binomialResult: any;
//public binomialResultSource: BehaviorSubject<IBinomialResult>;

//constructor(
//  private http: HttpClient) {
//  this.url = "api/BinomialResult/GetBinomialResult/0/0";
//  this.binomialResult = this.http.get<IBinomialResult>(this.url);
//  this.binomialResultSource = new BehaviorSubject<IBinomialResult>(this.binomialResult);
//}

//getBinomialResult(inputValues: any) {
//  this.url = "api/BinomialResult/GetBinomialResult/" + inputValues.failureCount + "/" + inputValues.demandCount;
//  this.binomialResult = this.http.get<IBinomialResult>(this.url);
//  this.binomialResultSource.next(this.binomialResult);
//} }
```

The portion that is commented out  is functional to the extent that it displays the binomialResult in the template as hoped for, demonstrating that I am getting the desired data from my controller, however, it will not update on a call to .next().  The current code (not commented out) displays nothing at all.

Here is my angular component:

```
@Component({
selector: "bionomial-result",
templateUrl: './binomial-result.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./binomial-result.component.css']
})

export class BinomialResultComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() class: string;
title: string;
errorMessage: any;
binomialResult: any;
inputForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
    @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string,
    private dataService: DataService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder    ) {
    this.inputForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'priorType': [''],
        'failureCount': [''],
        'demandCount': ['']
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.binomialResult.subscribe((result: any) => this.binomialResult = result);
}

onSubmit() {
    this.dataService.getBinomialResult(this.inputForm.value);
} }
```

And here is part of my component template I currently using for testing:

```
 <h4>Summary</h4>
   <pre>{{binomialResult.Output}}</pre>

   <p>
     This is a test: f = {{binomialResult.Failures}}, D = {{binomialResult.Demands}}
   </p>
```

I have found may examples on the web and this represents my best effort to follow along, but so far no success.  My best guess is that binomialResult is not reflecting what is in the binomialResultSource.  Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're really, really overthinking this. It should be reduced to this, as shown in the [HttpClient guide](https://angular.io/guide/http).

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBinomialResult(inputValues: any): Observable<IBinomialResult> {
    const url = `api/BinomialResult/GetBinomialResult/${inputValues.failureCount}/${inputValues.demandCount}`;
    return this.http.get<IBinomialResult>(url);
  } 
}


export class BinomialResultComponent {
  binomialResult: IBinomialResult;
  inputForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.inputForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'priorType': [''],
        'failureCount': [''],
        'demandCount': ['']
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.dataService.getBinomialResult(this.inputForm.value)
      .subscribe(result => this.binomialResult = result);
  } 
}

 <h4>Summary</h4>
 <div *ngIf="binomialResult">
   <pre>{{ binomialResult.Output }}</pre>

   <p>
     This is a test: f = {{ binomialResult.Failures }}, D = {{ binomialResult.Demands }}
   </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Ok, that does work and provides an immediate solution.  Thankyou!   I am still not understanding why I get nothing when I subscribe to binomialResult directly or why my BehaviorSubject does not work as the info on the web says it should.   However, I can use your solution until my understanding is better.